# If statement between 2 cycles

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[enter image description here][1]I have an excel data which has a column of different applications and each application is assigned with date and their respective cycle number.Each cycle has a date period of 180 days or 6 months and there are only 2 cycles (i.e) cycle1 and cycle2. These cycles have their respective dates. So, I am trying to write an if statement so that if there is only one cycle happening through that entire year, it should say "fail" else if it is passing through 2 cycles (cycle1 + 180days = cycle2) then it should say "pass".

Can anyone help me with this?

Excel sheet demo:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU9c9.png - please look at this link, to have a better understanding of the scenarion

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is properly sorted, I think this will do the trick.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,"cycle1")=1,COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,"cycle2")=1),"pass","fail")
```

put it in E2 and drag downwards..

Hope it helps.

Comment: you're welcome. ( : you may press the tick button to mark this question as 'answered' . Glad it helps.

Comment: I tried using a different scenario, please check the attached link, its not working now [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNtzJ.png

Comment: can you help me with this ?

Comment: In the pics you've attached, the words is "Cycle 1" and "Cycle 2" .. not "cycle1" and "cycle2".. The string evaluation is CaseSensitive.. just change the text in the formula and it should work. just fine.. if it didn't.. please share the one you'd tried. ( :

Comment: Yes that's correct, and also the columns in the first and second pic has interchanged. But still there is a conflict. I am attaching the link hope you would see it. The highlighted rows should pass, but they are failing. I couldn't figure it out. Hope you would.    See the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAqaV.png                                                                                                                                                                Thanks, D.

Comment: In this case there is more than 1 instance of `com` & 'cycle1' in column C. So the part `..   ,"cycle1")=1` in the formula is false.. that's why it shows 'fail' instead of 'pass' if more than one instance of the `com` & 'cycle1' is an acceptable condition, then just change the formula to `..   ,"cycle1")>=1` and do it for cycle2 too..

Comment: Yes I understood the logic @p._phidot. But you din't get my point. I explained in the below figure. Thanks for all the help. I mean it                                                                      https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRQ29.png                                                       Thanks D

Comment: if I understand it right.. then 'Infolink', and 'Portal' should be fail too .. coz the date difference is < 180 days.. right?